# Erlang argument passing

Tags: erlang

I've just started using Erlang and I can't get something to work

```
-module(bla).
-export([start/0, sendC/2]).

start() ->
    number = 236,
    Pid1 = spawn(dz, sendC, [1, number]),
    register(a, Pid1).

sendC(num, time) ->
    io:format(" ~w ~w \n", [num, time]).
```

I want to pass a number to another function. I get an error "exception error: no match of right hand side value 236".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`number` is an atom, and isn't equal to `236`.

Use `Number` instead. That way you get a variable. Of course, the same thing also goes for the parameters to `sendC`. You probably want `sendC(Num, Time)`.

The first letter determines whether the word is an atom or a variable: Lower case for atom, upper case for variable.

Comment: In aadition, the code line 6 is spawning dz:sendC/2 , not bla:sendC/2